# guardar varios archivos pdf en java

Tags: java

buenas noches lo q estoy tratando de hacer es abrir varios pdf a la vez y guardarlos con el mismo nombre el problema es q le hice asi y me creo un ciclo infinito

```
                for (int z=0;z<ficheros.length;z++){
                    try {


                        PdfReader leer = new PdfReader(ruta_archivo);
                        try {
                            PdfStamper agua = new PdfStamper(leer, new FileOutputStream(ficheros[z]+"_copiamarca.pdf"));





                            agua.close();
                            leer.close();
                        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }


                }
```

Comment: No veo por qué esto pueda generar un ciclo infinito. Lo que si que veo raro es que en el bucle siempre leas el mismo archivo (`ruta_archivo`). Una de dos, o lo que quieres es leer archivos diferentes cada vez, o sino a lo mejor te vendría bien sacarlo fuera del bucle ya que estarías leyendo lo mismo una y otra vez. ¿Puedes indicar que contiene el array ficheros?

Comment: si mi objetivo es capturar varios archivos diferentes y que se guarden todos los que se leen con el mismo nombre q el original

Comment: lo que debe  contener el array es archivos pdf los q quiera el usuario